# clearInterval stopping setInterval working purely time based

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, clearinterval

I'm newbie in JS/jQuery, and got quite confused about the usage of stopping a setInterval function from running in x ms (or after running X times), which apparently happens with clearInterval. I know this question was asked similarly before, but couldn't help me.

As you see, it starts with 1000ms delay, and then repeat for 9000ms (or after running 3 times if better??), and then it needs to stop. What's the most ideal way of doing this? I couldn't properly use the clearInterval function. Thanks for the answers!

```
var elem = $('.someclass');

setTimeout(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        elem.fadeOut(1500);
        elem.fadeIn(1500);
    },3000);
},1000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop the interval you need to keep the handle that `setInterval` returns:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var cnt = 0;
    var handle = setInterval(function() {
        elem.fadeOut(1500);
        elem.fadeIn(1500);
        if (++cnt == 3) clearInterval(handle);
    },3000);
},1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a counter, and keep a reference to your interval.  When the counter hits 3, clear the interval:

```
var elem = $('.someclass');

setTimeout(function() {
    var counter = 0;
    var i = setInterval(function() {
        elem.fadeOut(1500);
        elem.fadeIn(1500);
        counter++;
        if (counter == 3)
            clearInterval(i);
    },3000);
},1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Given what you are trying to do is quite static, why not simply add delays and forget all the timers.:

```
var elem = $('.someclass');
elemt.delay(1000).fadeOut(1500).fadeIn(1500).delay(3000).fadeOut(1500).fadeIn(1500).delay(3000).fadeOut(1500).fadeIn(1500).delay(3000);
```

Or run the above in a small loop if you want to reduce the code size:

```
elemt.delay(1000);
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
   elemt.fadeOut(1500).fadeIn(1500).delay(3000);
}
```

Comment: Using $.delay is the right way in general, if it comes to $.fn.animate. They want to switch from setinterval/settimeout to requestanimationframe. If you mix the requestanimationframe with normal timers, you can't sync them properly.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to clear the interval after three times:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var times = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        elem.fadeOut(1500);
        elem.fadeIn(1500);
        if (++times > 3) clearInterval(interval);
    },3000);
},1000);
```